# Triggering CI pipeline from CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In CI, I have a project that contains integration tests of many different app services that are already deployed. I want to trigger this CI pipeline automatically after I have deployed an app service in CD.

However, I don't see any option from CD to trigger the CI pipeline. Is there a way to do this without using an extension?

Comment: Do you use YMAL pipeline with deployments or Classic Release pipelines?

Comment: Thanks foe your comment @KrzysztofMadej Classic release pipelines

Comment: Your integration tests shouldn't be a separate pipeline. They should be a separate job within your release environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DanielMann. Why would that be better though? Wouldn't a dedicated pipeline that contains the tests for all services be better as it opens up options to trigger it on a scheduled basis for example?

Comment: Check if my answer helps to resolve your original issue and feel free to let me know if that helps or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I don't see any option from CD to trigger the CI pipeline. Is
>   there a way to do this without using an extension?

For your original question `Is there a way to do this without extension`: The answer is **Yes**.

You can call [Azure Devops Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to queue your build pipeline in a [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops). [Queue-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is the one designed to queue the build pipeline.

We can add a powershell task as the last task of your agent job to run Queue-build api, the script would look like this:

```
$token = "xxx"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganizationName/YourProjectName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "definition": {
    "id": BuildId
  } 
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

Write-Host "result = $($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

You should replace the YourOrganizationName and YourProjectName with your orgName and projectName. Also, you need to create a PAT with necessary permissions and enter it in `$token = "your PAT"`. And the BuildId in your $JSON is the ID of your build pipeline, you can easily find the value of that when editing your pipeline:

[image]

If you configure the task correctly, every time when your release is deployed successfully, it will trigger the build pipeline as the last step of your deployment.

Above is the way to trigger build pipeline in release pipeline, but actually this is **not recommended** way in most situations. We **normally** use build to trigger release instead triggering build using release!

Agree with **Daniel Mann**, you may consider move the build tasks **from the build pipeline to one job in release pipeline**,  they should be a separate job within your release environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out!

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help, if there's any error during this process, feel free to let me know with error message. I'll check for you :)