# How to pass parameters to trigger pipelines from another repo in Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let's say I have a pipeline A and I want to trigger a pipeline B (in another azure repo) from some parameters (eg. pipeline name and repo name).

Example:

```yaml
# Pipeline A
parameters:
  - name: pipelineName
  - name: repoName

steps:
  - run ${{ parameters.pipelineName }} from ${{ parameters.repoName }}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You may use rest api with `System.AccessToken` to queue another build:

1. [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)
2. [Triggering CI pipeline from CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483358/triggering-ci-pipeline-from-cd/61498851#61498851)
3. [User PowerShell to Queue a Build in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235103/user-powershell-to-queue-a-build-in-azure-devops)